# Snake script is not passing values to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is my snake script -

http://jsfiddle.net/6bKHc/24/

I started to create a snake game, but basically move(top), move(bottom) e.c. is not working. Any ideas why? I understand that I can't pass the elements to variable like this, so maybe you could show me how to do that correctly?

Comment: For one thing there is no CSS property called `value`. For another jQuery's `position()` method does not return a number but an object instead. That object's `left` and `right` properties are numbers representing the x and y coordinates of the HTML element in question.

Comment: Well, I see, but I need to replace the value with passed element via move(top), move(bottom) e.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok cleared syntax and took a look at errors this should get you started

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    var move, inter;
    inter = setInterval(move = function() {
        var dir = $(".snake").data('dir');
        var snake = $('.snake');

        if(dir == 'top') {
            snake.stop().animate({"top": "+=5px"});
        }
        if(dir == 'bottom') {
            snake.stop().animate({"top": "-=5px"});
        }
        if(dir == 'left') {
            snake.stop().animate({"left": "+=5px"});
        }
        if(dir == 'right') {
            snake.stop().animate({"top": "-=5px"});
        }
    }, 500);
    if(event.which == 40) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','top');
    } else if(event.which == 39) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','left');           
    } else if(event.which == 37) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','right');        
    } else if(event.which == 38) {
       $(".snake").data('dir','bottom');    
    }; });​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bKHc/36/)

Couple of obvious additions to make:

- boundary checking
- smoothness of animation.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you will have to moodify your code like follows :

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
    var inter;
    return function(event) {
        var move, prevDirection;
        clearInterval(inter);
        inter = setInterval(move = function(direction) {
            var value, prop;
            switch (direction || prevDirection) {
            case "top":
                prop = "top";
                value = -5;
                break;
            case "bottom":
                prop = "top";
                value = 5;
                break;
            case "left":
                prop = "left";
                value = -5;
                break;
            case "right":
                prop = "left";
                value = 5;
                break;
            }
            if (direction) prevDirection = direction;
            $(".snake").css(prop, $(".snake").position()[prop] + value);

        }, 500);
        if (event.which == 40) {
            move('bottom');
        } else if (event.which == 39) {
            move('right');
        } else if (event.which == 37) {
            move('left');
        } else if (event.which == 38) {
            move('top')
        };
    }
}());​
  ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bKHc/42/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6bKHc/29/ still not owrking, please check. I need that when you press arrow down, arrow left, arrow right, arrow up the green dot will start moving +5px on the direction.

Comment: @user1446087, i have not fixed your game, i fixed the javascript errors so that you can move forward. I have also not updated the fiddle, the revised code is in this answer

Comment: `css({
            value: $(".snake").position().value + 5 + "px"
        });  ` Doesn't make any sense :|

Comment: @Esailija, that is not my code... check his original fiddle, I only fixed the obvious syntax errors

Comment: @epoch I have edited it now but consider that the op won't stop until you code the full solution for him... this is why you should carefully consider not answering [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)